# Implementing OR in firestore query - Firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying implement logical OR operator in firestore query.

```
db.collection('users').where('company_id', '==', companyId)
                          .where('role', '==', 'Maker')
                          .where('role', '==', 'Checker')
                          .where('role', '==', 'Approver')
                          .get().then(function(adminsSnapshot){


             //Some processing on dataSnapshot
})
```

But this is not the right way to implement OR.

I want all users with roles of 'Maker, Checker or Approver'.

How would i implement OR in firestore query ? There's nothing in Doc.

Comment: what is the default role?

Comment: Two years later, this is now possible.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

**Edit (November 2019)**
Cloud Firestore now supports "IN" queries ([announcement](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html)) which allows you to do a type of OR queries that look for documents with one of a few values on the same field.

For example for the query above:

```
db.collection('users')
  .where('company_id', '==', companyId)
  .where('role', 'in', ['Maker', 'Checker', 'Approver']);
```

---

**Original answer**

There is no "OR" query in Cloud Firestore.  If you want to achieve this in a single query you will need a single field like `maker_or_checker_or_approver: true`.

Of course you can always do three queries and join them on the client.

Comment: I am making 3 queries. That's what I am doing. Yes

Comment: So, if I have let's say something like twitter, and i want to see only the tweets of people I follow, i can not say `tweets.where(user == john OR lisa OR julia)`?

Comment: Hi Guys. Has there been any updates to the node SDK yet? Multiple queries still seems an inefficient way to filter on multiple fields!

Comment: You can track progress on the OR feature here: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129070817

Answer (score 1):

This is now being made possible in Firestore by newly-added support for both the `in` and `array-contains-any` operators, which allow querying for up to 10 values in a single query.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/11/cloud-firestore-now-supports-in-queries.html

So, using your example, the query would look something like this.

```js
db.collection('users')
    .where('company_id', '==', companyId)
    .where('role', 'in', ['Maker', 'Checker', 'Approver']);
```

In the above example substitute `in` for `array-contains-any` if your data is stored in an array.

Comment: I am trying to use your query but get error "Invalid value "in" provided to function Query.where() for its second argument. Acceptable values: <, <=, ==, >=, >, array-contains". please help me how can i resolve this error

Comment: It may not be implemented in the client library you're using yet.  Last I checked, it was only implemented in the latest versions of the NodeJS and Python SDKs.  It'll likely roll out to more client libraries as time goes by.

Answer (score 1):

FTI `OR` queries now available in Preview :)

Source: https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/release-notes#March_24_2023

Answer (score 0):

You could combine the observables using rxjs, see angular(6) example below;

```
orQuery(){

    const $one = this.afs.collection("users", ref => ref.where("company_id","==","companyId")).valueChanges();
    const $two = this.afs.collection("users", ref => ref.where("role","==","Maker")).valueChanges();

    return combineLatest($one,$two).pipe(
        map(([one, two]) => [...one, ...two])
    )
}

getOr(){
    this.orQuery().subscribe(data => console.log(data))
}
```

Comment: or... ```const combinedList = combineLatest<any[]>(fooPosts, barPosts).pipe(
      map(arr => arr.reduce((acc, cur) => acc.concat(cur))))```

Comment: How about paginate data using query cursors and implement OR on multiple fields?

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Firestore does not natively support OR queries, but there are some ways to simulate this behavior:

#### Method 1: Multiple Queries and Client-side Merge

You can perform multiple queries and then merge the results on the client-side. This might be feasible for small datasets but can be inefficient for large datasets due to higher read costs and increased complexity in client-side code.

Here's an example in JavaScript:

```js
const db = firebase.firestore();

async function orQuery() {
  const query1 = db.collection("items").where("field1", "==", "value1");
  const query2 = db.collection("items").where("field2", "==", "value2");

  const [snapshot1, snapshot2] = await Promise.all([query1.get(), query2.get()]);

  const results = [];

  snapshot1.forEach(doc => {
    results.push(doc.data());
  });

  snapshot2.forEach(doc => {
    // Avoid duplicates
    if (!results.some(result => result.id === doc.id)) {
      results.push(doc.data());
    }
  });

  return results;
}
```

#### Method 2: Use an Array Field for Filtering

If the field you want to query can have a finite set of values, you might use an array to store these values and then use an `array-contains` query to filter documents that contain any of the specified values.

For example, suppose each document has a field `tags` that is an array. You can then query for any documents that have either "tag1" or "tag2":

```js
const query = db.collection("items").where("tags", "array-contains", "tag1");
```

You would still need to make multiple queries for each tag and then merge them on the client side:

```js
const queries = ["tag1", "tag2"].map(tag => 
  db.collection("items").where("tags", "array-contains", tag).get()
);

const allResults = await Promise.all(queries);

// Merge logic here
```

#### Method 3: Compound Fields

If you are trying to perform an OR query on multiple values of a single field, another option would be to create a compound field that combines these values and then query against that.

While these methods are not as straightforward as having native OR query support, they offer ways to achieve the same result. Choose the one that best fits your specific needs and limitations.