# Firebase query OR

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, data-modeling, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know if firebase can query this scenario:
I'm searching for people who has a dog and/or a cat.
Result should be that i get user1 and user2

```
{
  "users": {
    "user1": {
      "pets": {
        "dog": true,
        "cat": true
      }
    },
    "user2": {
      "pets": {
        "rabbit": true,
        "cat": true
      }
    },
    "user3": {
      "pets": {
        "bird": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Solution could be for FireStore or Realtime Database

Comment: Neither Firebase [Realtime Database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29560088/firebase-equivalent-to-sql-where-in) nor [Cloud Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore) can query on multiple values of a property (unless those values are in a range). So there is no equivalent for SQL's `SELECT * FROM users WHERE pets IN ("dog", "cat")`.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen how do i have to model my database, that i can do these query? Any advise?

Comment: If you check Sam's answer on the Firestore link I provided, an option he proposes is to create a `"has_cat_or_dog"` property. Another alternative is to run a query for each option and merge the results client-side.