# How to query the firestore with multiple .where

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a function that returns all the products, if and only if a specific category is defined inside the object.

What I am trying to do is to pass an array parameter on the function with an array of categories names like `[banana, apple, orange]` and I want to get all the products that have these fruits as categories.

the problem is, I need to pass an array in that function.

```js
const categories: string[] = ['apple', 'banana', 'orange'];

get_sugested_products_by_category(categories) {
   this.products_collection = this.afs.collection('products', ref =>
     ref.where(`category.${category}`, '==', true)
   );
   return this.products = this.products_collection.valueChanges();
}
```

> And I was thinking if is possible to make a query like this bellow:

```js
categories.forEach(category => {
  this.products_collection = this.afs.collection('products', ref =>
    ref.where(`category.${category}`, '==', true)
);
```

Comment: There is no way to such an OR or IN query in Firestore at the moment. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore. I have a feeling you'll want an inverted collection for this lookup, similar to what I do here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40656589/firebase-query-if-child-of-child-contains-a-value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing OR in firestore query - Firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore)