# Firestore "Logical OR" Query

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want to give my users the functionality to find their friends through their contact list. Every user has his phonenumber in their document. My data structure looks like this:

```
user {
 username: 'abc',
 email : 'abc@abc.com'
 telephone: '+293184192123'
}
```

I know that there are many posts about the Logical OR, which are saying it doesnt work without an workaround, but I couldn't find a workaround in my specific situation.

And in the worst cast, is it ok to query maybe 100 queries one after another ? And is there something simular to BatchWrite for Read calls ?

**EDIT**:
Here is an example how maybe a query would looked alike

```
db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("telephone", "+123456789")
                      .orEqualTo("telephone", "+777772423")
                      .orEqualTo("telephone", "+4923842959"); //And so on, you get the Idea
```

These telephone numbers will get readed out from the local storage from the Android Phone. So these phonenumbers are basically the contacts of the app user.

Comment: What's the query you intend to do that uses the Logical OR?

Comment: I updated my first post. Thank you for your help

Comment: Firestore currently does not support an OR of values in a single field. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47019670/209103). You'll have to read then in separate queries, or (if possible) by doing a single range query as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46726925/209103).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Do you think that it is ok to make queries successively like in my amount ? I mean an averrage user would have min. 100 contacts. And how can I chain them together ? Is there a way like a BatchWrite ?