# How to query IN array with Firestore?

Tags: arrays, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore collection, I have a string field called `username`. When receiving a list of username, I would like to find all matching docs. Something similar to this SQL query:

```
WHERE username IN ('Bob', 'Alice', 'Troy', ...);
```

Every time, I might have an array of up to 200 users and I would like to query for all matching documents. Couldn't find any reference for it in the documentation...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Implementing OR in firestore query - Firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore)