# Firebase (Vue) get by (multiple) child value

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I get all the games from a firebase collection. This gamescollection is looking like following:

```
{
    zgaHRO2yW6lafg1ubz4y : { // This is a game
        createdOn: Timestamp,
        finished: false,
        game: "TNhII8jDU23GUZyyqH5X",
        players: {
            NJ2U5MwVAIww6TWkHMv2: true,
            lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1: true
        },
        startedBy: "lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1"
    },
    QSkjMQS1232ezklmqKSDJoi : { // This is a game
        createdOn: Timestamp,
        finished: false,
        game: "TNhII8jDU23GUZyyqH5X",
        players: {
            AQSDNJ2U5MwVAIwWkHMv2: true,
            lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1: true
        },
        startedBy: "lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1"
    }
}
```

To get all the games, I perform the following action:

```
const gamesCollection = db.collection('games')
firebase.gamesCollection.where('finished', '==', false).orderBy('createdOn', 'desc').onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
    querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const games = doc.data()
    })
})
```

This works nice: I get all the games that are not finished yet... But now I want to "query" them like such:

1. Get all the games where player `lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1` is involved.
2. Get all the games where player `lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1` OR player `NJ2U5MwVAIww6TWkHMv2` is involed

Can't seem to figure out how it's done...

Answer (score 0):

Since you stored the players in a map, **for the first case** you can query for the `players` object property corresponding to the `playerId`, as follows:

```
  const playerIdToCheck = 'AQSDNJ2U5MwVAIwWkHMv2'
  const gamesCollection = db.collection('games')

  gamesCollection
    .where('players.' + playerIdToCheck, '==', true)
    .onSnapshot(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
        const games = doc.data()
        console.log(doc.id, ' => ', games);
      });
    });`
```

---

**For the second case** (the 'OR' query), actually it is not possible to execute OR queries as such in Firestore: you will therefore have to execute the two queries (i.e. one for lfNFlKnsbuUJGwINcJ4RMXbNVfs1 and one for NJ2U5MwVAIww6TWkHMv2)  and merge them in your front-end.

You can red more about OR queries and possible work around here: [Implementing OR in firestore query - Firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore) or here https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=firestore%20OR%20query