# Flutter multiple where case is not working

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Is that possible to get value based on multiple  doc id ?

```
CollectionReference col1 =  Firestore.instance
        .collection('service');
     col1.where("title", isEqualTo:"Ac replaciment")
    .where("title",isEqualTo:"Oil Service")
        .getDocuments()
```

This code not give any result

```
 CollectionReference col1 =  Firestore.instance
            .collection('service');
         col1.where("title", isEqualTo:"Ac replaciment")

            .getDocuments()
```

This code i got result
But i have title with both "Ac replaciment" and "Oil Service" but when i call tougher it is not giving result 

I need query like where `title =="Oil Service" or title =="Ac replaciment"` How todo this in firestore with flutter

When i run this code it return all data from server

```
CollectionReference col1 = Firestore.instance.collection('service');

    col1.where("title", isEqualTo: "Ac replaciment");

    col1.getDocuments().
```

but i only need to get result if `title=="Ac replaciment"` why this issue happening ?what is the correct code?

Comment: Cloud Firestore does not support OR queries. The common workaround is to fire a separate query for each condition, and merge client-side. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore

Comment: I think my answer to another thread may help with your issue
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72148576/13764313

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can think of two solutions.

**1. Push two separate query calls and concatenate the result.**

This might result in longer data retrieval as you send two separate query to the server.

```
CollectionReference col1 = Firestore.instance.collection('service');
final acReplacimentList = await col1.where("title", isEqualTo: "Ac replaciment").getDocuments();
final oilServiceList = await col1.where("title", isEqualTo: "Oil Service").getDocuments();
return acReplacimentList.documents.addAll(oilServiceList.documents);
```

**2. Filter documents locally.**

This might be a faster solution but it will expose all other unnecessary documents.

```
CollectionReference col1 = Firestore.instance.collection('service');
final allList = await col1.getDocuments();
return allList.documents.where((doc) => doc["title"] == "Ac replaciment" || doc["title"] == "Oil Service");
```

**UPDATED**

**3. Use Query Snapshots**

```
CollectionReference col1 = Firestore.instance.collection('service');
final snapshots = col1.snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.documents.where((doc) => doc["title"] == "Ac replaciment" || doc["title"] == "Oil Service"));
return (await snapshots.first).toList();
```

Comment: if i am using firebase database then there is an option to perform this in one query with out loading all data . Using firestore is a wrong option?

Comment: Is there any other way ? your 2nd method is expansive and 1st method is very slow

Comment: What you are saying is multiple where case is not supported by firestore?

Comment: I just had some more research. The current filter can only execute basic conditional statements. I think you'll need to call and map through query snapshots to enable a more complex filter. I'll update my answer and let's see if it suits your need.

Comment: now i am doing your 1st soluction but i am not intrested to acept your answer becase i am waiting to get more answer to suit my need . sorry

Comment: How about the third solution? It sends the query as a basic stream that is very customizable. It only calls the server once and does not expose all documents.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. Please use some online grammar check or translator to help you communicate your idea.

Comment: please explain, if my collection "service" contains 100 doc and when i use 3rd method is it   make 100 doc read for selecting only selecting 3 doc from the list?