# Cloud Firestore inequality operator exception flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

while i have been using cloud firestore in my flutter app, strange exception occured.

**EDITED**

**this is my code**:

```
Stream<List<Product>> productsStream(int id) async* {
    final k = _db
        .collection('products')
        .where('category_id', isEqualTo: id)
        .where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
        .orderBy('order')
        .snapshots();

    yield* k.map((event) => event.docs
        .map((e) => Product.fromJson(
              e.data(),
            ))
        .toList());
```

Here what i would like to achieve is to check for a product wether it is in stock and **then** to order products in an ascending order by `order` field in my `products` collection.

[image: Here is my collection fields]

But i am receiving this strange error:

> Exception:
> 'package:cloud_firestore/src/query.dart': Failed assertion: line 421 pos 16: 'field == orders[0][0]': The initial orderBy() field '[[FieldPath([order]), false]][0][0]' has to be the same as the where() field parameter 'FieldPath([stock])' when an inequality operator is invoked.

What might be solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firestore multiple range query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658651/firestore-multiple-range-query)

Comment: @SimonSot no it is not i assume.

Comment: That's not s strange error - it's correct based on your code and covered in the Firestore Documentation [Order Limitations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations) *If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field* so you would have to change your orderBy to 'stock' to remove the error.

Comment: @Jay By strange i meant that it is unclear error for me bc i am new on FB. thanks for clarifying. i know that if i change `orderBy('order')` to `orderBy('stock')` it will got fixed. but what i would like to achieve is simultaneously check for a product quantity in stock and then to order products in an ascending order using `order` field in my `products` collection. how can i achieve that? could you give a hand?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is explained in the [ordering limitations documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#limitations):

> If you include a filter with a range comparison (<, <=, >, >=), your first ordering must be on the same field

So I suspect you should have:

```dart
        .where('category_id', isEqualTo: id)
        .where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
        .orderBy('stock')
        .orderBy('order')
```

Obviously that means it's no longer *primarily* ordered by `order`. You'd need to do local sorting if that's a problem - in which case you may find you don't want to order server-side at all.

Although "not equal to" filters aren't mentioned in the documentation, it sounds like they also count as range comparisons in terms of prohibiting filtering.

So basically, I would suggest you *either* need to filter locally on `stock`, or you need to order locally on `order` - you can't do both in the same Firestore query at the moment. Note that this server-side limitation is something that *could* change in the future (either for all range comparisons, or possibly just to allow "not equal to") so it may be worth retesting periodically.

Comment: okay so when i do format my code like this `_db.collection('products').where('category_id', isEqualTo: id).orderBy('stock').where('stock', isNotEqualTo:0).orderBy('order', descending: false).snapshots();`  then it will sort in the way that products whose **stock** quantity is 0 won't appear and will be ordered by **order** field in an ascending order simultaneously?

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809: No, that code would still order by `stock` first - unless you *want* to order by stock, you should remove the `.orderBy('stock')` part. (As an aside, I would suggest putting all of the filtering first, then all of the ordering... it's simpler to read that way.)

Comment: i have done what you have suggested. but still same error. Could you please reread my question again. i have **edited** it

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809: Your edited code still has `.where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)`, which is the cause of the problem.

Comment: `isNotEqualTo` is also giving the same error. what might be the problem?

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809: That sounds like it counts as a range filter, unfortunately. If you change it to `isEqualTo` (just for test purposes) does the query then succeed? (Obviously it won't give you the results you want, but that's a different matter.) I'm surprised by it failing though... I might try the same thing myself later on in C#.

Comment: It is working with `isEqualTo`. i still didn't get what might be real problem( isn't there workaround?

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809: It sounds like that's a filter limitation then, basically. The only workarounds I can think of would be to either filter locally or sort locally.

Comment: i will omit orderBy from above query and will do ordering locally after data fetch. how can i order locally by ascending order? any help?

Comment: @Ruslanbek0809: I don't know Dart at all, so can't help you with that... and to be honest, that's a pretty unrelated question to how you'd do it server-side.

Comment: thanks for your effort and help. you informed me well. i will try workaround.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to do these two things. (it worked for me as shown in the example down below).

1 - Add an index for *stock* as Ascending in the console. This index should be in ascending.

2 - You must query based on that index.. So, as opposed to doing

```
...
.where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
...
```

You should be doing

```
...
.orderBy('stock', descending: false)
.where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
...
```

***This applies to all other composite indexes that have equality checks.*** So you may need to do that for *category_id*

## Also, here's my code for example

> For context. I'm displaying a chat list, where the number of messages are greater than 0, and of-course, where the current user is a participant

1 - In GCP *https://console.cloud.google.com/firestore/indexes/composite?project=**your-project-name***
I added the required index as such
[Composite index setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUrdM.png)

2 - Then finally, in my flutter code

```
static Future<QuerySnapshot> getUsersChatsList(String userId,
  {DocumentSnapshot? startAfterDoc, int limit = 10}) =>_chatsRef
    .where('participants_ids', arrayContains: userId)
    .orderBy('message_count', descending: false)
    .where('message_count', isNotEqualTo: 0)
    .orderBy('last_message_created_at', descending: true)
    .limit(limit)
    .get();
```

Ignore the *limit* & *startAfterDoc* as that was done for pagination

### **NOTICE** that I had to manually order *message_count* in ASC before checking the condition.

And finally, of course, they're sorted in DESC in time.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you are ordering with the same constraint as your where like this:

```
   getInventory() async {
    String value = user.uid;
    return inventoryFirebaseReference
        .orderBy('availableStock')
        .where('userFirebaseId', isEqualTo: value)
        .orderBy('availableStock')
        .where('availableStock', isGreaterThan: 0)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((event) {
      chargeProducts = false;

      final _documentList = event.docs;

      //print(_documentList.length);

      _documentList.map((e) => {});

      List<ProductMoof> listProductsProv = _documentList.map((doc) {
        ProductMoof inventoryItemProv =
            ProductMoof.fromMap(doc.data() as Map<String, dynamic>);

        inventoryItemProv.firebaseId = doc.id;

        return inventoryItemProv;
      }).toList();

      listInventory = listProductsProv;

      notifyListeners();

      print('Update gotten from Menu');
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Stream<List<Product>> productsStream(int id) async* {
final k = _db
    .collection('products')
    .where('category_id', isEqualTo: id)
    .orderBy('category_id')
    .where('stock', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: 1)
    .orderBy('stock')
    .orderBy('order')
    .snapshots();
     
yield* k.map((event) => event.docs
    .map((e) => Product.fromJson(
          e.data(),
        ))
    .toList());
```

Comment: this should work . because you need to add "orderBy" of every "where"