# How should I query the firestore data by datetime?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my firestore database, there is datetime table. For example :

```
date : 2022년 10월 3일 오전 3시 11분 22초 UTC+9
due_to :2022년 11월 2일 오전 3시 11분 22초 UTC+9
```

I want to load data that has later 'due_to' than DataTime.now().
So I made a code :

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('topic')
  .where('category',isEqualTo: catName) 
  .where('due_to',isLessThanOrEqualTo:Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()))
  .orderBy('vote', descending: true)
  .limit(num_topic_limit)
  .snapshots(),
```

But I saw an error saying,

> The initial orderBy() field "[[FieldPath([vote]), true]][0][0]" has to be the same as the where() field parameter "FieldPath([due_to])" when an inequality operator is invoked.

I don't understand why 'vote' field and 'due_to' field is being compared here, since using multiple where() without datetime field occurred no error.

What should I do to accomplish my goal ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is a bit weird, but it's trying to tell you that you need to add `orderBy('due_to')` before you can have the `where` clause on that field.

So:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('topic')
  .where('category',isEqualTo: catName) 
  .orderBy('due_to')
  .where('due_to',isLessThanOrEqualTo:Timestamp.fromDate(DateTime.now()))
  .orderBy('vote', descending: true)
  .limit(num_topic_limit)
  .snapshots(),
```

This also immediately means that the results will be in the order of `due_to` and only then in order of `vote` if they have the same `due_to` value. If that is not how you want to show the results, you'll have to re-order them in your application code.

I recommend checking out the [Get to know Cloud Firestore](https://firestore.video), to learn more about Firestore - specifically the episode on queries: [How do queries work in Cloud Firestore?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ofux_4c94FI&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLluG5MCVEzXAQ7ACZBCuZgZ&index=2)

Answer (score 1):

Firestore queries can only sort or filter range on a single field.Firestore only allows queries where it can meet its performance guarantees, and for ordering/range-filtering on multiple fields that is not (currently) possible.

The [Firestore documentation on queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) contains the examples of a valid and invalid query.

> **Valid**: Range filter and orderBy on the same field
>
> ```
> citiesRef.whereGreaterThan("population", 100000).orderBy("population");
> ```
>
> **Invalid**: Range filter and first orderBy on different fields
>
> ```
> citiesRef.whereGreaterThan("population", 100000).orderBy("country");
> ```

You can also check these stackoverflow threads [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66829643/cloud-firestore-inequality-operator-exception-flutter), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54244722/firestore-invalid-query-am-i-using-indexing-wrong) & [link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68917097/trying-to-order-firestore-results-in-query)