# Flutter firebase Query

Tags: database, firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am attempting to queuing my Firestone database however whenever I add multiple .where clauses to my query the query fails. Might there an obvious reason for this? I've attached my query below.

Thanks in advance.

**Not Working version (show ordered posts for today but the user logged in)**

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _todayStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("Todo")
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: user_database().getUID())
  .where('date',
      isLessThan: fetchDate().getToday())
  .orderBy("date", descending: false)
  .snapshots();
```

**Working version (show all results for posts made today regardless of user logged in)**

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _todayStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
   .collection("Todo")
  .where('date',
      isLessThan: fetchDate().getToday())
  .orderBy("date", descending: false)
  .snapshots();
```

**Working version (only show results posted by user logged in)**

```
 final Stream<QuerySnapshot> _todayStream = FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection("Todo")
  .where('uid', isEqualTo: user_database().getUID())
  .snapshots();
```

Comment: Following should be a good solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/56207500/11212287

Comment: What is the error message you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

Queries with multiple conditions need you to define an index yourself, something that isn't needed for queries with only a condition on a single field.

Check the log output of your app, because that contains a message with a direct link to create the necessary index, with all fields pre-populated.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Frank. Being new to flutter (and coding) I'm unsure how to access the output logs of my program. in particular how to produce a log relevant to the stream referenced above. Might you have any advice on how to do this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Additionally, might there be a solution where I could somehow create multiple queries and join them together. Just for the sake of simplicity. (again new to coding and having a tough time understanding many of the more complicated queries). Thank you in advance