# Is there any way to use OR query with Firestore RecyclerAdapter?

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

I have a recyclerview using Firestore Recyclerview Adapter, Now I want to show the list by using OR query.
For example I want to show the list which are either in "Pending" state OR "Assigned" state using query. I know firestore doesn't have OR query inbuilt but I want to achieve this anyhow. Any alrernative solution.

I have stored 4 state in firestore db : Pending, Assigned, Accepted and Completed. 
Only want to show pending or assigned

Below is my code:

```
    Query query = requestVehiclesCollectionReference
            .whereEqualTo("clientId", id)
     // show list which are in Pending state or Assigned state
            .whereEqualTo("status", "Pending")
            .orderBy("createdAt", Query.Direction.DESCENDING);


    FirestoreRecyclerOptions<Item> options = new 
    FirestoreRecyclerOptions.Builder<Item>()
            .setQuery(query, Item.class)
            .build();
```

Comment: Just use two queries one for pending and one for assigned. Then you have to validate which one of them you want to use outside your query.

Comment: Bring all the data once and put if condition inside data.

Comment: How to set two query inside FirestoreRecyclerOptions, since it support only one query ?

Comment: @Fortray You could use a if-statement for example. Just try to find out how it fits best in your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Firestore doesn't support queries with OR conditions. See:

- [Implementing OR in firestore query - Firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47018212/implementing-or-in-firestore-query-firebase-firestore)
- [How to perform compound queries with logical OR in Cloud Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46632042/how-to-perform-compound-queries-with-logical-or-in-cloud-firestore)
- [Firebase Firestore - OR query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46726673/firebase-firestore-or-query)

The common workaround is to use multiple queries (one for each condition) and merge the results in your application code.

FirebaseUI's adapters show data from a single query or collection. They have no option to show the results from multiple queries/collections.

From this combination it follows that you can't show data from an OR condition with a single FirebaseUI adapter. You will have to create you own adapter for this, although you can certainly use the (open-source) FirebaseUI adapters for inspiration.